# Cannot install Pylint on my company network

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, proxy, http-proxy, pylint

i'm having issue installing Pylint in VS Code.
When i type :

pip install pylint --trusted-host=pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --proxy=http://proxy-web.companyname.com:80

it gaves
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pylint (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pylint

Anybody can help with this?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pip install pandas --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --proxy=http://proxy-web.company.com:80

resolved by adding this, need to replace with company's proxy

Answer (score 1):

as the [documentation](https://docs.pylint.org/en/1.6.0/installation.html) says, you can try to install with the source code.

[here's](https://pypi.org/project/pylint/#files) the source file (The .gz) file.

once you extracted, and are on a terminal (or cmd) on the extracted directory.
run:

```
python setup.py install
```

Or you can install it in editable mode, using

```
python setup.py develop
```